# How to create my own extension that is also available in web-GUI

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We'd like to develop a GCP Dataflow extension that we can make available to our data engineers in the Dataflow pipeline builder GUI. I thought I understood that is possible in one of the webinars, but can't find any documentation about it. An example project would also be great.

thanks a lot for your help
Juergen

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is [Cloud Dataflow templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/overview), so your memory is correct. From these public docs there are sublinks on how to [create](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates) and then [run](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/running-templates) your custom templates.